# Extract Register Values in Gem5

Tags: x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, gem5

I want to extract the register values for every clock cycle and save them into a csv file using gem5. I want to extract data like the following

```
tck R0 R1 ........ R32
1   FA 3B ........ B1
2   A2 BC ........ 4C
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing my research on RISCV O3CPU. I found [a file online](http://doxygen.gem5.org/release/v22-0-0-2/riscv_2regs_2int_8hh_source.html) which defines the RISCV's architecture register ID.

So I write following code in o3/cpu.cc::tick:

```
 const std::vector<std::string> IntRegNames = {
    "zero", "ra", "sp", "gp",
    "tp", "t0", "t1", "t2",
    "s0", "s1", "a0", "a1",
    "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5",
    "a6", "a7", "s2", "s3",
    "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7",
    "s8", "s9", "s10", "s11",
    "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6"
};

for(int i=0;i<IntRegNames.size();i++){
    RegId my_reg(IntRegClass,i);
    std::cout<<IntRegNames[i]<<" has value "
    <<getArchReg(my_reg,0)<<std::endl;
}
```

With my asm code

```
 li      a1,5
 li      a2,6
```

That's the result looks like

```
zero has value 0
ra has value 0
sp has value 9223372036854775600
gp has value 0
tp has value 0
t0 has value 0
t1 has value 0
t2 has value 0
s0 has value 0
s1 has value 0
a0 has value 0
a1 has value 5
a2 has value 6
a3 has value 0
a4 has value 0
a5 has value 0
a6 has value 0
a7 has value 0
s2 has value 0
s3 has value 0
s4 has value 0
s5 has value 0
s6 has value 0
s7 has value 0
s8 has value 0
s9 has value 0
s10 has value 0
s11 has value 0
t3 has value 0
t4 has value 0
t5 has value 0
t6 has value 0
```

It looks like you can use a similar way on X86. I hope this can help you.